# I was trying to make a code that stores a certain information of someone for some tests but something wrong could someone help me?

Tags: discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def His(ctx, message):
  with open("names.json", "ab+") as ab:
    ab.close()
    f = open('names.json','r+')
    f.readline()
    if os.stat("names.json").st_size == 0:
      f.write("{}")
      f.close()
    else:
      pass
    with open('names.json','r') as f:
            names = json.load(f)
            print('Names Open')

    def save_name(names, user):
      if not f'{user.id}' in names:
       names[f'{user.id}'] = {}
      names[f'{user.id}']['names'] = 0
      print(f"{users[f'{ctx.author.id}']['names']}")
  msg = message
  await ctx.send (msg),
  save_name
  await client.process_commands(msg)
```

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'author'

If someone could explain some arguments to me I would be even more grateful as I am new to Discord.py.

I would be grateful if someone would help me! :)

Comment: Can you include more of the traceback please?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you havent specified the author in your code so make your `save_name` line to `save_name(names,message.author)`